# VBA scan for specific documents and then copy/paste?

Tags: vba, search, copy-paste

Can VBA scan for xlsm documents and withdraw information into other worksheets given a set of word banks? I'm trying to automate copy and paste into a summary workbook but the problem is the names of the documents are always different (constraint). Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Yes it's possible, you can loop on the files in the folder, regardless of file name. You can utilized it using `Dir` function

Comment: how would you tell it to search for different files though, as the names change

Comment: This [link](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/23/loop-through-all-excel-files-in-a-given-folder) provide a good explanation about the loop on files, regardless of file name.